# it create a record but it is empty

Tags: php, ajax

well I am trying to insert user data and I made these codes , the record is being created but there is no data in it , just to clarify I have include the files and I am connected to the database and I think I declared all the necessary objects , if you know what is wrong I would appreciate a bit more explaining I am a beginner

addUser.php

```
<div id="message" class="flex-row align-center flex-nowrap">
        <h4 class="heading flex-1"></h4>
    </div>
    
    <div class="flex-row form-row">
        <div class="flex-column create-session-sidebar__column">
        <form class="form" method="post">

                <div class="Faseeh-form-input outlined"><label class="label">الاسم الاول</label>
                <input id="fname" placeholder="" type="text" value=""></div>

                <div class="Faseeh-form-input outlined"><label class="label">الاسم الثاني</label>
                <input id="lname" placeholder="" type="text" value=""></div>
                
                <div class="Faseeh-form-input outlined"><label class="label">اسم المستخدم</label>
                <input id="username" placeholder="" type="text" value=""></div>

                <div class="Faseeh-form-input outlined"><label class="label">البريد الالكتروني</label>
                <input id="email" placeholder="" type="email" value=""></div>

                <div class="Faseeh-form-input outlined"><label class="label"> الالكتروني</label>
                <input id="password" placeholder="" type="password" value=""></div>
                <div class="flex-row form-row">  
    <button id="addUser" class="Faseeh-btn Faseeh-btn Faseeh-btn-primary" type="submit">تسجيل</button>
    </div>
    </form>
    </div>
    </div>
   
</div>
```

```
<script>
   
     $(document).ready(function() {
       NewUser();
     });

     function NewUser() {
        $(document).on('click', '#addUser', function() {
            var fname = $('#fname').val();
            var lname = $('#lname').val();
            var username = $('#username').val();
            var email = $('#email').val();
            var password = $('#password').val();

            var data = "fname=" + fname + "&lname=" + lname + "&username=" + username + "&email=" + email + "&password=" + password;

            if(fname == "" || lname == "" || username == "" || email == "" || password == ""){
                $('#message').html('Please fill in the blanks');
            }else{
                $.ajax ({
                url: 'core/register.php?',
                type:'post',
                data: data,
                success: function(data) {
                    $("#message").html(data);
                }

            });
            }

            
        });
     }
</script>
```

and this is register.php

```
    <?php
include_once "util.php";
session_start();
$util = new util();  
$post = $_POST['data']; 
$data = json_decode($post);

$result = $util->newUser($data);
if($result) {
    echo 1;
}else {
    echo 0;
}
```

and finally util.php

```
public function newUser($data){

    // Our database object
    $db = new dbhandler();    
    // Quote and escape form submitted values
    $fname = $db -> quote($fname->fname);
    $lname = $db -> quote($lname->lname);
    $username = $db -> quote($username->username);
    $email = $db -> quote($email->email);
    $password = $db -> quote($password->password);
    
    // Insert the values into the database
    $result = $db -> query("INSERT INTO `users` (`fname`,`lname`,`username`,`email`,`password`) VALUES (" . $fname . "," . $lname . "," . $username . "," . $email . "," . $password . ");");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost! 2 problems though.

1. You are sending in the data as a url format, but you are reading it as a JSON format. Instead of

```
var data = "fname=" + fname + "&lname=" + lname + "&username=" + username + "&email=" + email + "&password=" + password;
```

You need to create an object with:

```
var data = array(
   "fname": fname,
   "lname": lname,
   "username": username,
   "email": email,
   "password": password
}
```

2. You need to get the variables from inside the `$data` object you passed in.

```
public function newUser($data){

    // Our database object
    $db = new dbhandler();    
    // Quote and escape form submitted values
    $fname = $db -> quote($data->fname);
    $lname = $db -> quote($data->lname);
    $username = $db -> quote($data->username);
    $email = $db -> quote($data->email);
    $password = $db -> quote($data->password);
    
    // Insert the values into the database
    $result = $db -> query("INSERT INTO `users` (`fname`,`lname`,`username`,`email`,`password`) VALUES (" . $fname . "," . $lname . "," . $username . "," . $email . "," . $password . ");");
}
```